# Rolling updates take the old instance configuration and place them in the new one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was wondering if when the rolling updates happen, the new instance have some of the changes that I did manually inside the instance, like configuring some listening ports on the nginx proxy server and things like that.

Comment: No, you shouldn't be doing any changes manually, because they will be lost during new deployments, or auto-scaling actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rolling updates do not work like that. They **terminate** the instances during the update and deploy new ones.

Docs [write](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rollingupdates.html):

> During a rolling update, capacity is only reduced by the size of a single batch, which you can configure. Elastic Beanstalk takes one batch of instances out of service, **terminates them, and then launches a batch** with the new configuration. After the new batch starts serving requests, Elastic Beanstalk moves on to the next batch.